# Amazon App Store Submission: Filtering Devices Based on RAM Via Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

So we're planning to submit our android game in the amazon app store.
From testing across a range of devices, we have found that the game runs well on devices that have at least 768mb of ram. Not so well on devices that only have <=512mb.

I know that *ideally* the solution would be to make the game more robust on these weaker performing devices..but assuming that is not a solution..what would be the ideal configuration to include in the manifest so that we could filter out, not all, but many of these weaker performing devices.

I understand that we have the following filters at our disposal,
http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html 
but the problem is that using the filters at our disposal, it seems I am unable to target something like ram or performance on a device.

Anyone have any suggestions as to how I might target RAM indirectly? or target "higher performing" devices via the manifest?

(Also, Amazon does not offer the ability to filter devices on a device-by-device basis like Google Play offers, so that is unfortunately not an option.)